# Python3 pop() function only deleting strings

Tags: python-3.x

I am taking a beginners Python course and am currently creating this sample dictionary:

```python
dictVar = {25:"The square root of 5","Vitthal":"SOME DUDE'S NAME",3.14:"Pi"}
```

The course is teaching how to use an interactive prompt to request the name of a Key in the dictionary which assigns it to the variable "inputKeyToDelete"

```python
inputKeyToDelete = input("Please enter the key you wish to delete from the dictionary. Your key to delete is: ")
```

When I enter the key Vitthal the key-value pair is deleted, but when I enter the key 25 or 3.14 nothing occurs which is the cause for my question.

the instructor is using the following to perform the lookup\delete.

```python
if inputKeyToDelete in dictVar:
    dictVar.pop(inputKeyToDelete)
    print("Ok, the key-value pair for Key '" + inputKeyToDelete + "' has been removed.")
```

Any tips is appreciated.

Comment: dictVar = {"25":"The square root of 5","Vitthal":"SOME DUDE'S NAME","3.14":"Pi"} try this

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. This worked but broke other examples in the course such as:


print("The Value corresponding to the Key " + str(3.14) + " is: " + dictVar[3.14])

and


print(dictVar[3.14])

Answer (score 2):

`input` always returns a string in python 3. `"25" != 25` in python, so the key isn't found. You need to add code to deal with numeric keys. Here is one  way:

```
inputKeyToDelete = input('enter a number:')
try:
    inputKeyToDelete = eval(inputKeyToDelete)
except NameError:
    pass

print (inputKeyToDelete)
print(type(inputKeyToDelete))
```

Or just change your example to only use string keys.

**Note:** In python 2, `input` would convert to integer for you, which might be confusing you a bit.

Comment: This was extremely helpful, especially the last bit on python2 vs 3. I think this course was based off of python 2 and I have been struggling trying to use python 3 while following. I have a lot to learn!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with below line. Take user input and type cast to int because python takes string as a input.

```
inputKeyToDelete = int(input("Please enter the key you wish to delete from the dictionary. Your key to delete is: "))
```